# Why do big wall harnesses have two belay loops?

Tags: gear, rock-climbing, aid-climbing

I've been looking at big wall harnesses and I've been noticing that a lot of them come with two belay loops:

[image]

[image]

I know that it isn't there as a back up. What's the advantage of having two belay loops on your harness when aid climbing?

Comment: what harness is that by the way? Thanks

Comment: @Dakatine http://www.firstascent.co.uk/climb/ocun-quattro-tech-harness.html apparently

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simply for organization sake.

Aid climbing on big-walls involves lots of gear, and you'll very quickly realize how much of a mess your perfectly racked gear will become.

With two belay loops you can separate your aid ladders and daisy chains a little, which helps to keep them from wrapping around each other (and keep things a little bit cleaner too).

[image: Pete's picture from MP showing gear quantities]

Couldn't find a good close-up picture for you, but Pete's picture from MP is a good visual indication of exactly how much is going on around your belay loop sometimes when climbing big-walls.

Chris McNamara talks about it a more in his book on big wall climbing also. http://www.supertopo.com/a/How-To-Big-Wall-Climb-Table-of-Contents/a139n.html

Comment: Aid climbing: the "siege tactics" version of climbing...

Comment: That's a terrifying picture! My risk management head just keeps picturing a tangle at a critical moment...